# How to build a mongo $in query in C++

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm wondering how to build an $in query in C++.  I am able to successfully build a $nin query like this:

```
mongo::BSONArrayBuilder bab;
bab << "category1";
bab << "category2";

mongo::BSONObjBuilder bobQuery;
bobQuery << "category" << mongo::NIN << bab.arr();
```

However, there does not appear to be a corresponding mongo::IN to build the corresponding $in query.  At least, I can't find one digging through the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
mongo::BSONObjBuilder bobQuery;
bobQuery << "category" << BSON( "$in" << bab.arr());
```

or

```
mongo::BSONObjBuilder bobQuery;
mongo::BSONObjBuilder catQuery;

bobQuery.append("$in", bab.arr());
catQuery.append("category", bobQuery.done());
```

Comment: @victor1234 - please ask a new question rather than asking in a comment.